# How to print variable inputs with operators in python

Tags: python, printing, operators

My goal is to carry out the instructions below:

> Enter integer:
>
> 4
>
> You entered: 4
>
> 4 squared is 16
>
> And 4 cubed is 64 !!
>
> Enter another integer: 5
>
> 4 + 5 is 9
>
> 4 * 5 is 20

Here is my code:

```py
user_num = int(input('Enter integer:\n'))
    
print("You entered: ", user_num)
    
print(user_num, "squared is ", user_num*user_num)
    
print("And", user_num, "cubed is", user_num*user_num*user_num, "!!")
    
user_num2 = int(input("Enter another integer:\n"))
    
print(str(user_num) + str(user_num2), "is", user_num+user_num2)
    
print(str(user_num) * str(user_num2), "is", user_num*user_num2)
```

The problem is that the last two lines of my codes are not giving me what I want. I want the inputs for user_num and user_num2 to be printed in a non-concatenated way and without execution to read, for example, "4 + 3 is 7" and "4 * 3 is 12". Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Take advantage of [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) so your print construction is easier to produce.

A corrected solution would look like the following:

```
user_num = int(input('Enter integer:\n'))

print(f"You entered: {user_num}")
print(f"{user_num} squared is {user_num**2}")
print(f"And {user_num} cubed is {user_num**3}!!")

user_num2 = int(input("Enter another integer:\n"))

print(f"{user_num} + {user_num2} is {user_num+user_num2}")
print(f"{user_num} * {user_num2} is {user_num*user_num2}")
```

Comment: Thank you very much Anderson. This is really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

```
user_num = int(input('Enter integer:\n'))
print("You entered: ", user_num)
print(user_num, "squared is ", user_num*user_num)
print("And", user_num, "cubed is", user_num * user_num * user_num, "!!")
user_num2 = int(input("Enter another integer:\n"))
print(str(user_num), "+", str(user_num2), "is", user_num+user_num2)
print(str(user_num), "*", str(user_num2), "is", user_num*user_num2)
```

When you want to print the operators, you have to put them in quotation marks

Answer (score 2):

You could do it like this:

```
print(str(user_num), "+", str(user_num2), "is", user_num+user_num2)

print(str(user_num), "*", str(user_num2), "is", user_num*user_num2)
```

Notice how i replaced `+` and `*` in your code to the string `"+"` and `"*"` respectively.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The code you wrote seems good but you will get errors at last two lines cause you are trying to add and multiply two strings which are not possible. So you can do this

```
user_num = int(input('Enter integer:\n'))

print("You entered: ", user_num)

print(user_num, "squared is ", user_num*user_num)

print("And", user_num, "cubed is", user_num*user_num*user_num, "!!")

user_num2 = int(input("Enter another integer:\n"))

print(user_num, '+', user_num2, "is", int(user_num)+int(user_num2))

print(user_num, '*', user_num2, "is", int(user_num)*int(user_num2))
```

also editing the last two lines

```
print(str(user_num), '+' ,str(user_num2), "is", user_num+user_num2)

print(str(user_num), '*' ,str(user_num2), "is", user_num*user_num2)
```

Comment: Thank you very much Sasidhar. It worked. This is really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Use [f-strings](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/formatted-string-literals-f-strings-python/).

Here is my code:

```
unum1 = int(input('Enter integer:\n'))

print(f"You entered: {unum1}")
print(f"{unum1} squared is {unum1**2}")
print(f"And {unum1} cubed is {unum1**3}!!")

unum2 = int(input("Enter another integer:\n"))

print(f"{unum1} + {unum2} is {unum1+unum2}")
print(f"{unum1} * {unum2} is {unum1*unum2}")
```

Comment: Thank you very much Yourson. This is really helpful.

Answer (score -1):

```
user_num = int(input('Enter integer:\n'))

print('You entered:',user_num)

print(user_num, 'squared is', user_num * user_num)

print('And', user_num, 'cubed is', user_num * user_num * user_num,'!!')

user_num2 = int(input('Enter another integer: \n'))

print(user_num, '+', user_num2, 'is', user_num + user_num2)

print(user_num, '*', user_num2, 'is', user_num * user_num2)
```

Comment: This seems to be a poorly formatted copy of an existing answer.